# How can I save a matplotlib plot that is the output of a function in jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm actually working on a project using google colaboratory. I'm using the pygad module(a Genetic Algorithm module). After running the algorithm, one can obtain the plot of a function, the fitness function, in such a way:

```
resultplot = ga_instance.plot_result()
```

Which returns the plot when executing the cell. However, the output of the function is `None`. If I use the `resultplot.savefig('plot.png')` function in this case I get an error.

Is there another way of saving the image with a command? Without having to use left click + save image as.

Thanks!

Comment: `ga_instance.save(filename=filename)`According to [the manual Exsample](https://pypi.org/project/pygad/), this is what saving to a file looks like.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but that saves the instance of the ga, not the resulting plot, which is what I'm interested about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io).

Unfortunately, the `plot_result()` method does not return the created figure and thus you cannot save it. But do not worry, you can still save the figure.

The `plot_result()` simply plots the data saved in the `best_solutions_fitness` attribute. This attribute can be accessed anywhere using the instance of the `pygad.GA` class.

You can simply use the `best_solutions_fitness` attribute to rebuild the figure and save it. Here is what you should do:

Rather than calling the `plot_result()` method, simply use the next code which creates the figure, shows the same plot created using the `plot_result()` method, and saves it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot

matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(ga_instance.best_solutions_fitness)
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig("PyGAD_figure.jpg")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Again, thanks for using [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io) :)

Comment: Awesome. Good luck!